# What is the "please-remove-this-tag" tag?

Tags: support, tagging, tags

I saw that [please-remove-this-tag](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/please-remove-this-tag) has been added to some questions, and then removed.
What is the purpose of that tag?
Is it a tag that has been renamed, and then removed? If this is the case, why should a tag be renamed, and then removed from questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just realized that because the tag itself will eventually disappear (as it already has), so will the wiki, and now the link in yossarian's answer is broken. So I'm including the original wiki in this answer for reference:

**Excerpt:**

> This tag is a placeholder tag intended to replace another, high-risk problem tag. Please review the full tag information (wiki) for instructions and guidelines for removal

**Wiki:**

> **What is this tag for?**
>
> [please-remove-this-tag](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/please-remove-this-tag) is used to help in the cleanup of high-risk problem tags.
>
> **What kind of tags are a problem?**
>
> A high-risk problem tag is defined as one that is:
>
> 1. Vague, ambiguous, misleading, regionally-dependent, [meta](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), or otherwise prone to misinterpretation and incorrect or inconsistent usage.
> 2. Easily discoverable - typically composed of common keywords present in the question.
> 3. Already in widespread use, such that an immediate manual removal of all instances of the tag would bump newer questions off the [front page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).
>
> Such tags are considered to be serious problems because their usage tends to become both more common and more divergent over time - even amongst experienced members.
>
> When it is impractical to "hand-sort" one of these tags due to volume, a moderator may merge the problem tag with [please-remove-this-tag](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/please-remove-this-tag) in order to quickly eliminate it from the [tags page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags) and any tag suggestion boxes, as well as leave a clear and easily-recognizable marker on the question itself that it will eventually require retagging.
>
> **When and how should I remove it?**
>
> Any members with the [retag question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) privilege may perform a retag.  See the aforementioned link for specific instructions on how to retag any questions.
>
> Some additional guidelines for this specific retag:
>
> - **Pay attention to other question tags.**  More often than not, questions with one bad tag will have other bad tags, and/or be missing other important tags.  Don't *just* remove the placeholder; treat it as any other retag and consider which tags would actually be most appropriate for the question.
> - **Don't mass-retag.** Limit your retag efforts according to our daily question activity; at the moment, we recommend no more than 10 retags on a typical day, less on weekends.  Be mindful of other members potentially doing the same thing; if you see more than a few old questions already on the front page, let it be - the placeholder will still be there tomorrow.
> - **Don't retag closed questions.** Closed questions are the short list for eventual deletion, at which point it won't matter what tags they have.  Don't add noise to the front page by bumping a question that has been deemed off-topic or inappropriate.
> - **Prioritize questions that are already on the front page.** New or bumped questions have their tags on display for the whole world to see.  If a front-page question has bad tags (including this placeholder), then don't hesitate or worry about site activity - retag it now.
>
> **More questions?**
>
> Check these posts for answers:
>
> - [Discouraging the proliferation of bad tags: Proposal](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/discouraging-the-proliferation-of-bad-tags-proposal)
> - [When should I retag a question?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/966/when-should-i-retag-a-question/968#968)
>
> If you still have questions, don't hesitate to ask them on [Meta Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

It's explained in the tag wiki: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/please-remove-this-tag/info

Basically, if there's a tag in use that we want to remove, rather than mass editing and pushing stuff to the top, we merge the tag to "plese remove" and then remove it a couple of questions at a time.

Comment: @aaronut, right. That's why I linked that in my answer. ;o)

Comment: I could have sworn that the answer linked to the original meta question... *sigh* must be more tired than I realized.